# How to re-match a group that did not capture anything?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a string in which a certain section can either be enclosed between `"` or `'` or not be enclosed at all.  However, I'm struggling finding a **syntax that works when no quotation marks are there at all**.

See the following (simplified) example:

```
>>> print re.match(r'\w(?P<quote>(\'|"))?\w', 'f"oo').group('quote')
"

>>> print re.match(r'\w(?P<quote>(\'|"))?\w', 'foo').group('quote')
None

>>> print re.match(r'\w(?P<quote>(\'|"))?\w(?P=quote)', 'f"o"o').group('quote')
"

>>> print re.match(r'\w(?P<quote>(\'|"))?\w(?P=quote)', 'foo').group('quote')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

**The desired result for the last attempt should be `None` as the second command in the example.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions I got to another question, I was able to produce a slightly different regex that provides the correct answers:

```
>>> re.match(r'\w(?P<quote>[\'"]?)\w(?P=quote)\w', 'foo').group('quote')
u''

>>> re.match(r'\w(?P<quote>[\'"]?)\w(?P=quote)\w', 'f"o"o').group('quote')
u'"'

>>> re.match(r'\w(?P<quote>[\'"]?)\w(?P=quote)\w', 'f\'o\'o').group('quote')
u"'"
```

The trick was really to **use a quantifier on the character matched rather than on the entire group**.

[ The leading and trailing `\w` in this example are just for preventing the regex to match the full string (as an unquoted string).  In the real case scenario this was not needed as this match is part of a larger regex with previous and later groups matched ].